# select also empty values

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have two tables that look like so

**users**

```
id
name
```

**loans**

```
id
borrower_id
lender_id
amt
```

i need to select all loans, matching their names in the select, so for the following data

**users**

```
id, name
1, mark
2, james
```

**loans**

```
id, lender_id, borrower_id, amt
1,  1,         2,           100
2, 2,          1,           150
3, NULL,       1,           500
4, NULL,       2,           300
```

the NULL are in the case of where a lender has not reponded. the output should be

```
loan_id, lender, borrower, amt
1,       mark,   James,   100
2,       James,  mark,    100
3,       --,     mark,   100
4,       --,     mark,   100
```

this is what i tried

```
Select
  loans.amt As amt,
  borrower.name As borrower,
  lender.name As lender,
  loans.id AS loan_id
From
  (users borrower Join
  loans On borrower.id = loans.borrower_id) Join
  users lender On lender.id = loans.lender_id
```

Comment: What is your Question?

Comment: A LEFT JOIN returns all entries from your main table with NULL values from the joined table. You should use the more verbose style with each joined table having it's own "JOIN ... ON" statements, makes life a lot easier.

Comment: I don't understand how the result set relates to the data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `LEFT JOIN` to include rows where only one table has rows which meet the criteria.

Try this:

```
Select
  loans.amt As amt,
  borrower.name As borrower,
  lender.name As lender,
  loans.id AS loan_id
From
  loans 
    LEFT JOIN users AS borrower ON loans.borrower_id = borrower.id
    LEFT JOIN users AS lender ON loans.lender_id = lender.id
```

Answer (score 0):

In oracle, instead of using left join, you can use (+) symbol.

For example,

select distinct 
l.id as loan_id,
u1.name as lender,
u2.name as borrower,
l.amt as amt
from users u1, users u2, loans l
where
u1.id(+)=l.lender_id and
u2.id(+)=l.borrower_id